# If singular set is finite then the ideal is radical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals, algebraic-curves

> Let $F\in K[X,Y]$ and if the zero set $V(F,\frac{\partial F} {\partial x},\frac{\partial F} {\partial y})$ is finite then $\sqrt {(F)} = (F)$.

I don't see the relation between $\frac{\partial F} {\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial F} {\partial y}$ and $\sqrt {(F)}$. I don't want whole answer, I think it will be good to see some  clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $(F)$ is not equal to its radical, which means that $F = G^2 H$ for some non-constant polynomial $G$.  Now try computing $V(F, F_x, F_y)$ and see
what you get.